# Use single quotes within a string for prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel-5, single-quotes

I have a Like condition in a query I need to filter on first and last name in a users table.
My variables are set up like this:

```
$firstname = Input::get('firstname');
$lastname = Input::get('lastname');
$myparameters = array();
$filterfirst = "'%" . $firstname . "%'";
$filterlast = "'%" . $lastname . "%'";
```

My sql query Is being set up like this (dynamically):

```
$sqlstring = 
                    "SELECT t1.id,t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t2.function "
                    . "FROM users t1 JOIN user_details t2 "
                    . "ON t1.id = t2.user_id";
            if($firstname && $lastname){
                $sqlstring .= " WHERE lower(first_name) LIKE lower(?)"
                        . " OR lower(last_name) LIKE lower(?)";
                $myparameters = [$filterfirst,$filterlast];
            }
            else{
                if($firstname){
                    $sqlstring .= " WHERE lower(first_name) LIKE lower(?)";
                    $myparameters = [$filterfirst];
                }
                if($lastname){
                    $sqlstring .= " WHERE lower(last_name) LIKE lower(?)";
                    $myparameters = [$filterlast];
                }
            }
```

My query is being executed using a Laravel prepared statement:

```
$resultset = DB::select($sqlstring,$myparameters);
```

I've logged the values of my important variables like this:

```
Log::info($sqlstring);
Log::info($myparameters);
Log::info('first name: ' . $filterfirst);
Log::info('last name: ' . $filterlast);
```

I'm seeing my logged values like this:

```
[2015-06-26 09:32:52] local.INFO: SELECT t1.id,t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t2.function FROM users t1 JOIN user_details t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id WHERE lower(first_name) LIKE lower(?) OR lower(last_name) LIKE lower(?)  
[2015-06-26 09:32:52] local.INFO: array (
  0 => '\'%jer%\'',
  1 => '\'%can%\'',
)  
[2015-06-26 09:32:52] local.INFO: first name: '%jer%'  
[2015-06-26 09:32:52] local.INFO: last name: '%can%'
```

So my values are correct '%jer%' and '%can%' which are the values I need to go into my query, but when I put them into my variables array they turn into '\'%jer%\'' and '\'%can%\'' So the sql command being executed isn't working correctly (returning nothing).

Does anyone have any idea how I can work around this? So I need the array to contain the string with a single quote without adding the extra single quotes or slashes so I just need '%whateverIgavein%'

EDIT: tried using a key value array and named variables in my sql statement but doesn't make any difference appearantly (as soon as it goes into the array it turns into '\'%whateverIgavein%\''

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/747609) should make things clear to you... change to `$filterfirst = '"%' . $firstname . '%"';`.

Comment: @iroegbu that's not it either, this returns nothing aswell, it generates my variable like this: '"%whateverIgavein%"' I need the single quotes next to the % operators, right now it just put double quotes inside the string, which doesn't work in mysql, I need single quotes

Comment: I found it, your answer pushed me in the correct direction @iroegbu it should have been like this:  $filterfirst = '%' . $firstname . '%'; Thank you so much for pushing me into the right direction

Comment: I'll let you have it cause I wouldn't have found it without you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the mistake of adding quotes to the content of your variable:

```
$firstname = "Joe";
$filterfirst = "'%" . $firstname . "%'";
var_dump($filterfirst) //string(7) "'%Joe%'" <-- notice the extra quotes
```

To include just the needed `%` to your string:

```
$filterfirst = "%{$firstname}%";
```

or

```
$filterfirst = "%" . $firstname . "%";
```

will both result in `string(5) "%Joe%"`